# Spring Data Elasticsearch - typeless

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch in my spring boot application. I need to save entities to index. However, I am getting this error:

> Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated, use the
>   typeless endpoints instead

service:

```
@Service
interface AddressRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Address, String> {

}
```

entity:

```
@Document(indexName="registry")
public class Address {

    @Id
    private String code;
}
```

How can I implement this in a typeless way and get rid of these errors?

Comment: Which versions of Spring Boot, Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using and which version has the Elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0.0.RELEASE, Elasticsearch 7.7.0

Comment: where do you see this message? I cannot reproduce this with the given versions. When your application starts, there should be log messages from the `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.support.VersionInfo` class at INFO level, showing which versions are really used by the program. What is logged there?

Comment: I feel very embarrassed. The warn log is gone now. Probably in time question I had in my pom.xml version of Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE (I am not sure)

So that versions were Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE, Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.7.RELEASE (Elastic 7.7.0). With these versions I am getting the error above at WARN level.
Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE doesn't have this problem.

Comment: yes, Spring Data Elasticsearch builds the request using Elasticsearch 6.8 libraries, and that would explain that.